# Can't edit a question because it contains too much code

Tags: support

I was editing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69705121/how-can-i-create-an-implementation-for-the-same-use-case-using-queue-with-an-int). I deleted some weird text under the question and format the code.

But then I submit the edit, and it says that most of my edit is code, please add some text.

I tried to add some words, eg:

> Here is my code:

But it still says the same error.

How can I resolve this?

edit: That question is deleted but the question still remains.

Comment: The OP has deleted the question now anyway, so somewhat moot. I did give the edit a go myself, and it worked fine though; not sure if that's because I have higher rep, or because you might have omitted the ending brace (`}`) outside of the code block. Though the error shown to the OP was correct; their question is mainly code; normally such questions end up being VTC'd for being unclear or not giving a [mre]. If you couldn't edit it, and the question is part of an area you have expertise it, you might have wanted to flag if for closure, or VTC it.

Comment: You often can't. At least not without either fabricating more descriptive text or removing code, and both may require a certain amount of telepathic ability to ensure you're not changing the intent of the question.